# Reverse Proxy of a TCP/UDP Port Using Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

When i tried to reverse proxy a port to another port in the same server, nothing happened.
I want to proxy UDP and TCP port to another port.

My nginx configuration file is like that:

```
stream {
    server {
    listen 8020;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8040;
    }
    server {
    listen 8020 udp;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8040;
        }   
}
```

Comment: what does `nginx -t` report?

Comment: @ti7 test is successful

Comment: @AmrAshraf Did you solve your problem? and how?